# More efficient way of setting default method argument to instance attribute

Tags: python, performance, oop

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing:

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.defaultVal = "default"

    def myMeth(self, valToDefault=None):
        if valToDefault is None:
            valToDefault = self.defaultVal
        else:
            ...
```

This gets repetitive and I'm sure there is a better method of doing it that I'm just not thinking of.

Comment: `valToDefault = self.defaultVal if valToDefault is None else valToDefault`? Or maybe `valToDefault = valToDefault or self.defaultVal`, if you want to replace any false-y value. But what do you do in the `else` case? Also note [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on naming conventions.

Comment: `*args` and best of all would be `**kwargs` i recon, you could make a wrapper that traverse a default map of sorts and that could be a solution.